# Making just one part of the class wait for execution, with or without threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am coding a space invaders clone, I need the invaders to do their usual movement but pause for one second before moving again.

EG. Move 5 pixels, then wait, then move another 5 pixels.

The method called **moveInvaders()** is the method I want to make wait for 1000ms. Below is that such method.

```
private void moveInvaders() {
        if(direction == "right") {
        if(invaderGreenEight.getX() == 455 || invaderRedEight.getX() == 455 || invaderBlueEight.getX() == 455) {
            direction = "left"; // Change direction to left
        }
    } else {
        if(invaderGreenOne.getX() == 15 || invaderRedOne.getX() == 15 || invaderBlueOne.getX() == 15) {
            direction = "right"; // Change direction to right
        }
    }

    if(direction == "right") {
        // Move Green Invaders Right
        invaderGreenOne.moveX(1);
        invaderGreenTwo.moveX(1);
        invaderGreenThree.moveX(1);
        invaderGreenFour.moveX(1);
        invaderGreenFive.moveX(1);
        invaderGreenSix.moveX(1);
        invaderGreenSeven.moveX(1);
        invaderGreenEight.moveX(1);
        // Move Red Invaders Right
        invaderRedOne.moveX(1);
        invaderRedTwo.moveX(1);
        invaderRedThree.moveX(1);
        invaderRedFour.moveX(1);
        invaderRedFive.moveX(1);
        invaderRedSix.moveX(1);
        invaderRedSeven.moveX(1);
        invaderRedEight.moveX(1);
        // Move Blue Invaders Right
        invaderBlueOne.moveX(1);
        invaderBlueTwo.moveX(1);
        invaderBlueThree.moveX(1);
        invaderBlueFour.moveX(1);
        invaderBlueFive.moveX(1);
        invaderBlueSix.moveX(1);
        invaderBlueSeven.moveX(1);
        invaderBlueEight.moveX(1);
    }
    if(direction == "left") {
        // Move Green Invaders Left
        invaderGreenOne.moveX(-1);
        invaderGreenTwo.moveX(-1);
        invaderGreenThree.moveX(-1);
        invaderGreenFour.moveX(-1);
        invaderGreenFive.moveX(-1);
        invaderGreenSix.moveX(-1);
        invaderGreenSeven.moveX(-1);
        invaderGreenEight.moveX(-1);
        // Move Red Invaders Right
        invaderRedOne.moveX(-1);
        invaderRedTwo.moveX(-1);
        invaderRedThree.moveX(-1);
        invaderRedFour.moveX(-1);
        invaderRedFive.moveX(-1);
        invaderRedSix.moveX(-1);
        invaderRedSeven.moveX(-1);
        invaderRedEight.moveX(-1);
        // Move Blue Invaders Right
        invaderBlueOne.moveX(-1);
        invaderBlueTwo.moveX(-1);
        invaderBlueThree.moveX(-1);
        invaderBlueFour.moveX(-1);
        invaderBlueFive.moveX(-1);
        invaderBlueSix.moveX(-1);
        invaderBlueSeven.moveX(-1);
        invaderBlueEight.moveX(-1);
    }
}
```

The game is already a thread and the method in question is in the same class so issuing Thread.sleep(1000); just pauses the entire game for 1 second, but I just want the execution of one method to pause.

If you want more information I am more than happy to provide it.

GeissT

Comment: No you may not need to create a separate distinct Thread directly. Please provide more information and some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `moveInvaders()` method should keep track of a member variable which stores the time the invaders were last moved (e.g. as a `long` number of milliseconds), this way, any time it is called it can check the value of that variable - if enough time has elapsed then the invaders can move, if not, then the method will simply return without doing anything.  For example:

```
protected long invadersLastMovedMillis;

protected void moveInvaders() {
  long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  if ((invadersLastMovedMillis != 0)
      && ((currentTime - invadersLastMovedMillis) < 1000L)) {
    return; // No need to move them yet.
  }
  // March on, space invaders!
  invadersLastMovedMillis = currentTime;
}
```

You don't want to actually cause the thread to sleep because the game will then become unresponsive!

Comment: So each time the 'moveInvaders()' method is called how might it check the time since last move? Would I use a 'for' loop to increment each time it's executed? But that would provide performance issues due to faster and slower processors. Hmmm.

Comment: @GeissT: each time you move the invaders update the variable with the current time in milliseconds; then you can check that variable each time before you consider moving them to see if enough time has elapsed.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you would use a Timer of some sort, but what sort will depend on many issues not yet known to us. What GUI library are you using?

For example, if this were a Swing GUI, I'd suggest using a Swing Timer for this delay -- but again, we've no idea what libraries  your using.

Bottom line: Please provide more information and code.

**Edit**: 
First suggestion: Get rid of all if (myString == "Foo"). You shouldn't compare Strings that way since this checks if one String object is one and the same as another, and you don't care about this. You want to know if they have the same content. Instead use the String#equals(...) or String#equalsIgnoreCase(...) methods.

Next: use arrays to reduce the severe code redundancy present.

Finally for a Swing app, consider using a Swing Timer to drive your game loop, and in the timer notify items listening to it of time ticks. Then have the items only respond after a certain amount of time has elapsed since their last action.

Comment: I am using Swing, Hovercraft.

Comment: @GeissT: you'll really want to tell us the details if we will have half a prayer to be able to answer this or other similar questions. Always write your questions assuming that we can't read your mind or magically see your code. I think you'll want to edit your original question and provide a lot more detail.

Comment: I will provide my moveInvaders() method for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create another thread (say T1) at the same level where you create game thread.

Start it after game thread is fully created OR when `moveInvaders()` method can be called without any crash.

ASA game thread ends, stop T1 also.

> The game is already a thread and the method in question is in the same class so issuing Thread.sleep(1000);just pauses the entire game for 1 second, but I just want the execution of one method to pause.

The problem is there is one class, one object and only one thread to execute. It should be one class, one object and two thread. (Game Thread and T1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have chosen another user's answer, but I will definately take this into consideration! :)